# Is there a difference between velocity and average velocity?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, vectors

Is there a difference conceptually between velocity and average velocity?

In my book, Velocity is defined as the derivative of a vector function: **v**(t) = **r**'(t)
where **r**(t) is a vector function.

Average velocity is defined as

Average Velocity $=\frac{\left(\vec{r}_b-\vec{r_a}\right)}{b-a}$
Where $\vec{r}_a$ is the vector position of a particle when t=a. And $\vec{r}_b$ is the vector position of the particle when t=b

If there is a difference between them, what is the difference?

Comment: Of course there is a difference between them: One is a derivative, and the other is not. Do you know what a derivative is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Velocity is the average velocity when $b-a$ goes to zero (derivative)

Answer (score 2):

Let's say I'm going around a circular track at $100$ MPH.

My velocity at any point is $100$ MPH along the direction I'm going. This is also an instantaneous velocity because it's a time derivative.

My average velocity over one lap is zero, because I start and end at the same point. I've been moving a lot, but on average I haven't gone anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Shortest answer:  average velocity does not require taking a limit.

Perhaps more enlightening:  Move 1 meter in 1 second at a constant velocity of 1 m/s.  Now wait.  The velocity while waiting is zero.  The average velocity starts at 1 m/s during the move and decreases during the wait, but is never zero.